# Using CSS to pull text to front (or image to back) with image that is randomly picked with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a simple page I'm playing around with, based on some examples I've found here and elsewhere.

I've got the javascript working to pick a random image to load on the page.

The problem is I also want text to be in front of the image.  I've tried a bunch of css options to try to pull the text forward or push the images back (z-index, etc) but using these in combination with the javascript doesn't work.  Even tried a couple different options of adding style information to the  tag, but none of it has worked.

Does anybody have an idea how to pull this off?  This seems like a formatting thing I'm overlooking, but it might be tied to the javascript.

Here's where I'm at right now:

```js
function random_pic(){
var pics=new Array();

pics[1]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[2]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[3]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[4]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[5]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[6]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[7]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[8]="http://placehold.it/350"
pics[9]="http://placehold.it/350"

var pic=Math.floor(Math.random()*pics.length);
if (pic==0){pic=1;}
document.write('<img src="'+pics[pic]+'" border=0>');
}
random_pic();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.style {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #003399;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p class="style"><strong>To protect the security of your account,<br> please close this tab or browser</strong></p>
```

Can't load the pics into the example above, but hopefully this is enough to see what's going on.

Comment: What text are you referring to, the paragraph with the security message? You want that on top of the image?

Comment: a simple solution would be have a div which you can change its bg through the js & while having the text already as a child of that div.

Comment: You are not assigning class .image to the image so absolute positioning will not be used. document.write('<img class="image" src="'+pics[pic]+'" border=0>');

Comment: Are you calling `random_pic();` after DOM is loaded i.e. on a button click etc. in your real code?

Comment: The images are like watermarks...they don't dominate the text...they're just a lite background for the message to sit on top of.

Comment: javascript is called when the page loads so no click is required

Comment: Gerard...I tried a couple different classes to put the image source into and they never worked....I'll give yours a shot...

Comment: Gerard....thanks....adding the class to the src did the trick....appreciate everyone's quick help with this!!!

Comment: I was trying to add the class to the random_pic (which I didn't show in what I posted because it broke everything).  Definitely a "face-palm" event on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I used based on Gerard's suggestion...

within the "document.write" at the bottom of the javascript, I put the image class before the src.  Thanks everyone!!!

```js
function random_pic(){
var pics=new Array();

pics[1]="../images/exit_1.png"
pics[2]="../images/exit_2.png"
pics[3]="../images/exit_3.png"
pics[4]="../images/exit_4.png"
pics[5]="../images/exit_5.png"
pics[6]="../images/exit_6.png"
pics[7]="../images/exit_7.png"
pics[8]="../images/exit_8.png"
pics[9]="../images/exit_9.png"

var pic=Math.floor(Math.random()*pics.length);
if (pic==0){pic=1;}
document.write('<img class="image" src="'+pics[pic]+'" border=0>');
}
random_pic();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.style {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #003399;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p class="style"><strong>To protect the security of your account,<br> please close this tab or browser</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers use a lot of heuristics to improve render times, and now, you're going against one of them. Let's think about this like a browser would:

1. The page loads and the browser sees the following HTML:

   ```
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <p class="style"><strong>To protect the security of your account,<br> please close this tab or browser</strong></p>
   ```
2. The browser can render this, so it does. When the JavaScript runs and the image is inserted, the browser has to completely change its view model, and doesn't know where to put things.

This process, in addition to being bad for performance, also produces inconsistent results. To solve this, you must let the browser know that some image will be there. You can do this one of several ways:

1. **Use `background-image`**. First, you must set the background to a color, upon initial load, so that when the image is loading, and if the image fails to load, the text is still legible.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var mes = document.getElementById("message");
  mes.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://unsplash.it/2100/1200/)"
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 padding: 32px
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="message">
  <h1>To protect your account, please close this tab</h1>
</div>
```

2. **Insert the image by default.** Put the image tag into the page source, and style it there, making sure to specify the final dimensions, and then change the `src` as you see fit. This one is simple enough that you shouldn't need a demo

Comment: Thank Monty....this works for a static image.  Need the dynamic javascript part to do what I want.  Gerard gave me the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use negative top margin to change the order or z-index. Have a look at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/XSH2Y/)

```css
.greenleftarrow{
position: relative;
z-index:10;
display:block;
background: green url(./images/greenleftarrow.jpg) no-repeat;
left:10px;
top: 0px;
height:140px;
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}

#over {
    margin-top: -140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="greenleftarrow"  id="greenleftarrow" ></div>
<div id="over">body body body body</div>
```

Comment: Thanks....this looks good, but it appears to be predicated on having a static path to the image....I understand how to do that.  My problem is dealing with random images generated from an array in javascript.  Thanks for the input though.

Comment: If anything, you'd want to use absolute positioning on the image & text (and have the parent have relative position) to achieve it. You're hardcoding some pixel value which A. may change and B. isn't responsive.